# install group_concat UDAF aggregate function in Vertica 8.0.0-2

Tags: c++, git, vertica

i got Vertica-Extension-Packages from git ([link](https://github.com/vertica/Vertica-Extension-Packages/tree/master/strings_package)) and i upgrade vertica from 7.2.0 to 8.0.0-2 and after the upgrade i try to recompile it so i go to the folder and type:

```
$make uninstall
$make install
```

after that i try to run:

```
select group_concat(node_name) over() from nodes;
```

and get this error:
ERROR 5861: Error calling getReturnType() in User Function group_concat at [src/GroupConcat.cpp:86], error code: 0, message: Function only accepts 1 argument, but 614891469...provided

Comment: If this was really a User Defined **Aggregate** Function you should use it with a GROUP BY...

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. I'd put a ticket in the github issue tracker.  You might be able to try using agg_concatenate instead, although it works a bit differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you run "make uninstall" try this:
$ make clean

And only afterwards do:
$ make install

Because "make uninstall" only "DROP LIBRARY StringsLib" from the database. However, your previous compiled version(s) still exists and might damage any future "make install" process.

What "make clean" does is removing your old build as follows:
        rm -rf build
        rm -rf lib
        rm -f vsim*
        rm -f test-data/wordlist_header.txt

Answer (score -1):

What you wanna do is put a partition or a grouping inside the over() stmt
See example :

```
select group_concat(node_name) over(partition by '') from nodes;
```

Hope this helped :)

Comment: hi, its not solve the problem i still get error that i get error that i send more the 1 argument